# Launching a program from browser with custom URI : is there any way to know if the user accepted?

Tags: javascript, browser

I'm launching an external program with a custom URI such as

```
hello://world
```

[This is surprisingly simple to do in Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx) and currently it works very well. So if I have the following HTML

```
<a href="hello://world">Link!</a>
```

and I click on the link, my browser shows a dialog asking for approval to launch the program similar to this one :

[image: dialog]

Is there any way to know through Javascript if the user accepted or refused the request?

Comment: afaik, not directly, but you might be able to tell with blur/focus events if they started doing something other than going right back to your tab.

Comment: @dandavis : Thank you for the tip! I'll investigate this today.